# How to create a simple shortcut name for long table names?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL developer, and my usual work is largely querying database tables with very long names.I don't have admin access to database, so I can't change the table names to short names.Plus it's a centralized database on which many people in many offices are working.To come to the point, I want to be able to have short reference names to these long table names which would be local to my SQL developer.For example, if table name is *I_am_a_long_name*, I want a short reference name like **IAALN** (The short name will be given by me)so I can write:

```
select * from IAALN;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If typing is a limiting factor when writing SQL you need to learn to type faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have enough privileges, you can create [synonyms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm):

```
CREATE SYNONYM IAALN 
   FOR somedb.I_am_a_long_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to use synynoms (as suggested by @Smileek). If you can't or don't want to do that, you could create a view for every table you want to query:

```
  CREATE VIEW IAALN 
  AS
  SELECT * FROM I_am_a_long_name;
```

and use these views in your ad-hoc queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can define constants for your long name, in the programing language you are using.
and then refer to those constants in the query like.

```
define(IAALN,'I_am_a_long_name')

sql = "select * from ".IAALN;
```

Or alias is another option

```
SELECT 
    IAALN.*,
FROM 
    I_am_a_long_name as IAALN;
```

Comment: Why do you assume any other language than pure sql?

Comment: I thought he need to use those in some script. so Constants can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

1st way:

> create table IAALN as select * from I_am_a_long_name;

after creating the table IAALN ...you can fire any select statement..

> select * from IAALN ;

2nd way:

> create or replace synonym IAALN for User_name. I_am_a_long_name;